# How can I stop my function from running the first 3 lines everytime?

Tags: python, function, websocket

I am trying to make and plot some graphs and compare some price data a little more efficiently than doing it by hand. Below I have included the code I have written so far, this has taken me the better part of 2 weeks.

I have successfully reached the Kraken websocket and have been able to gather the data I needed from the returned json.

I would like this all to fit into one neat function so when the time comes I can easily use a bunch of these in together.

Because of the bottom `while True` statement, lines 4 and 5 are repeating each time price data is printed...

When this snippet of code is not a function it behaves exactly as expected and returns/prints bid and ask price when they are changed.

```
def kraken_price():
    import websocket
    import json
    wskraken = websocket.create_connection("wss://ws.kraken.com/")
    wskraken.send('{"event":"subscribe", "subscription":{"name":"ticker"}, "pair":["XBT/USD"]}')
    while True:

        # websockets received data cast to a variable
        received = wskraken.recv()
        # if the received data is only a heartbeat it must be ignored

        if received == '{"event":"heartbeat"}':
            pass

        else:
            # takes the string received from the websocket and converts it to a json object
            jdata_loads = json.loads(received)

            try:
                krakenAsk = jdata_loads[1]["a"][0]
                krakenBid = jdata_loads[1]["b"][0]
                return krakenAsk, krakenBid

            except:
                print('connection to Kraken websockets is being established')

while True:
    print(kraken_price())
```

Comment: Are you trying to avoid recreating the websocket every time the function is called?  How about defining the websocket outside the function and passing it into the function as an argument?

Comment: If your using Python 3+, checkout the [websockets library manual](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend turning your function into a generator. That would allow for a much cleaner interaction between the caller and the function:

```
import websocket
import json

def kraken_price():
    wskraken = websocket.create_connection("wss://ws.kraken.com/")
    wskraken.send('{"event":"subscribe", "subscription":{"name":"ticker"}, "pair":["XBT/USD"]}')
    while True:

        # websockets received data cast to a variable
        received = wskraken.recv()
        # if the received data is only a heartbeat it must be ignored

        if received == '{"event":"heartbeat"}':
            pass

        else:
            # takes the string received from the websocket and converts it to a json object
            jdata_loads = json.loads(received)

            krakenAsk = jdata_loads[1]["a"][0]
            krakenBid = jdata_loads[1]["b"][0]
            yield krakenAsk, krakenBid

for ask, bid in kraken_price():
    print(ask, bid)
```

Imports generally go at the top of a script.

When you use `yield` anywhere in a function, it becomes a generator function. It now returns an iterable object that yields the required values in lockstep with your outer `for` loop.

You'll probably want to surround the lines of the generator function after the first with a `try: ... finally: ...` block to close the connection no matter how it works out. At that point, you may want to use context management on the connection.

Comment: Thank you so much for you response! after many hours of tinkering and trying to understand what you did, I finally do and that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @TooLate. Glad it worked out for you. Generators are a very neat concept. Welcome to python!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import websocket
import json

def kraken_price(wskraken,tickerpair):

   wskraken.send('{"event":"subscribe", "subscription":{"name":"ticker"}, "pair":["'+tickerpair+'"]}')

    while True:

        # websockets received data cast to a variable
        received = wskraken.recv()
        # if the received data is only a heartbeat it must be ignored

        if received == '{"event":"heartbeat"}':
            pass

        else:
            # takes the string received from the websocket and converts it to a json object
            jdata_loads = json.loads(received)

            try:
                krakenAsk = jdata_loads[1]["a"][0]
                krakenBid = jdata_loads[1]["b"][0]
                return krakenAsk, krakenBid

            except Exception as e:
                print('connection to Kraken websockets is being established')
                print('Exception was: ",e)

wskraken = websocket.create_connection("wss://ws.kraken.com/")

while True:
    print(kraken_price(wskraken,"XBT/USD"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

it does the right thing however I was hoping to cram all of that into the function as I am going to be pulling multiple different ticker pairs. I am going to take user input to decide on which connection string to send to the websocket.

Comment: Edited the answer to allow changed ticker pairs.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I was wondering about that.  I was going to suggest creating a class (or a just a global list) to contain "already subscribed" ticker pairs.

Comment: thank you for the response. This is not quite what I am looking for as i do not want the create connection to be an argument I have to enter into the code.

Comment: For some reason when I run this the except loop runs each time the price updates. Could you possibly explain why please?

Comment: I modified the except block to print the exception string.  That will give you a clue.